# What is the meaning of npm errors

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am new to npm. I am trying to run this command in my angular project

```
npm install jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2 --save
```

so I want to use this third party library `https://www.npmjs.com/package/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2`.

The problem is that when I run the command i get the following error in my console

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test-project@3.6.0-SNAPSHOT
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.11.1
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"0.11.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.10.3" from @angular/core@10.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~10.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 || >=7.0.0" from jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2@2.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2
npm ERR!     jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/common)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\a.user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

what does this error means and why I can't install this library ?

Comment: It means you're using Angular 10.2.1 which [depends](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/10.2.x/packages/core/package.json#L12) on Zone.JS 0.10.X, yet your `package.json` seems to require Zone.JS 0.11.1, which raises the error.

Comment: But why this error is raised when i try to install third party package ?

Comment: It's raised next time you try to install anything with a broken dependency tree.

Comment: So until i resolve that issue I can't install another package ? And when i try to install it with --force then my application is broken in other things.

Comment: Correct. Your application gets broken because you're trying to force unsupported dependencies. If a 3rd party library was not updated for e.g. Angular 10, chances are, it's going to break the application.

Comment: It's mean if you want to run this command: `npm install jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2 --save`, you can use `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`. For example `npm i jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2 --legacy-peer-deps`,